# Problems Using .on() with Dynamically Added Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-on

I read that [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated, and that I should use `.on` instead. But `.on` doesn't seem to be working for elements added to the DOM.

My script adds a table with any number of text boxes (`input type="text"`), and I want to run some script when the content in any of those text boxes changes.

Here's part of my code. `vendorsPopUp` references the div that contains my table.

```
$('input', vendorsPopUp).on('change', function (e) {
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

But this code does not run when the content in a text box changes.

Comment: you call on() on the table or body or div, not inputs, which have no sub-elements.  on() uses a parent container that watches any element under it for the event, not just the few elements found at time of binding; thats why it needs the extra selector argument. right now, you use on() in legacy mode.

Comment: Duplicate of many other questions.  I will go find a duplicate now.

Comment: @dandavis not legacy mode, in directly binding mode. there's nothing legacy about binding directly to an element.

Comment: Someone voted me down because the question has already been asked? I did a number of searches. I'm sorry, I just wasn't finding the right data. If it's closed as a duplicate, that's fine. But the person who downvoted just seems like a jerk.

Comment: legacy is perhaps pejorative, but there's no advantage to on() without delegation, and it might be misleading to coders expecting a sub-selector. without delegation, you might as well use a more semantic .change() handler.

Comment: @dandavis: I was told to use `.on` instead of `.click()`, etc. Are you saying you don't use `.on` for static elements?

Comment: @JonathanWood: both work, but .click() is more readable and faster to execute if you don't need to hit future elements. there's nothing wrong with on(), it's a powerful new feature, but just because you get a new hammer doesn't mean you have to use it on push pins...

Comment: You know, because `.click` doesn't forward directly to `.on('click'`. `</sarcasm>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this

```
$(vendorsPopUp).on('change', 'input', function (e) {
   alert($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

Comment: This is the right answer. It's clear and concise, and it has the code I need. That's fine if the question is closed as a duplicate. But I don't know why some people are so bent on downvoting. Especially those who do so without a comment.